# Remove-ADComputer : Access is denied powershell

Tags: powershell, access-denied

Long time lurker but I finally found a problem that I could not find an answer for so I decided it was time to join. Im trying to collect a list of computers in AD that are older than X days ($DelCompDays). Then based off of the DistinguishedName field delete that computer using the Identity flag. Problem is even with domain admin creds I am getting: Remove-ADComputer : Access is denied

Even if I run Remove-ADComputer -Identity "Full CN or Short name" I get an access denied. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
#Get AD computers older than $DelCompDays
$results = Search-ADAccount -ComputersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan "$DelCompDays.00:00:00"

#Loop and try to delete
foreach ($result in $results){
    if ($result -ne $NULL){
    try {
        Remove-ADComputer -Identity $result.DistinguishedName -confirm:$false
        $Success = "Deleted: $result.DistinguishedName"
        WriteCustomOutput -message "$Success" -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor DarkMagenta
    }
    catch {
        $Error = "Failed to delete: $result.DistinguishedName"
        WriteCustomOutput -message "$Error" -foregroundcolor Red -backgroundcolor Black
    } 
}   
else{
    $Warning = "No computers older than $ArcDays days to delete"
    WriteCustomOutput -message "$Warning" -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor DarkMagenta
}

}
```

Comment: Do objects have Accidental Deletion bit checked? Can you, maybe, take a look at one of the computer properties > Object Tab > See the checkbox at the bottom?

Comment: Thanks for the input, they do not actually. I figured it out and posted the answer below. Turned out to be an issue with the way remove-adcomputer passes credentials when running non-interactively. @AdilHindistan

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. When running non-interactive you need to specify the creds in the command call.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "ClearTextPass" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Username", $secpasswd)

Remove-ADComputer -Identity $result.DistinguishedName -Recursive -confirm:$false -credential $creds
```